# How to prevent Typescript from mismatching function params?

Tags: typescript, types

When I type the `fetchProfiles()`'s parameter as `fetchProfiles({idArray}: {idArray: string[]})` (in the bottom snippet), all it's neighbor function calls throughout the app, such as

```
import UserProfileState from 'state/UserProfileState'
const userProfileState = UserProfileState()
userProfileState.findProfile({ id })))
```

throw the error:

> (property) id: any
>
> Argument of type '{ id: any; }' is not assignable
> to parameter of type '{ id: any; } & { idArray: string[]; }'.
> Property 'idArray' is missing in type '{ id: any; }' but required in
> type '{ idArray: string[]; }'.ts(2345)
>
> UserProfileState.ts(79, 40): 'idArray' is declared here.

(line 79 of UserProfileState.ts is where `fetchProfiles({idArray}: {idArray: string[]})` is
declared)

as if it thinks the typed parameter `{idArray}: {idArray: string[]}` exists on `findProfile()`.

UserProfileState.ts:

```
import { useMemo } from 'react'
import { createState, useState } from '@hookstate/core'
import { mapValues } from 'lodash'

const initialState = createState({
  userProfiles: {}
})

const stateWrapper = (state) => {
  const wrapper = {
    findProfile({ id }) { 
        ...
    },
    async fetchProfile({ id }: { id: string }) {
        ...
    },
    async fetchProfiles({idArray}: {idArray: string[]}) {
        ...
    }
  }
  return mapValues(wrapper, (f) => (typeof f === 'function' ? f.bind(wrapper) : f))
}
const UserProfileState = () => {
  const state = useState(initialState)
  return useMemo(() => stateWrapper(state), [state])
}
export default UserProfileState
```

My app is currently using Typescript 3.8.3. Updating to 4+ did not resolve this issue.

Comment: What is `mapValues`? It might be destroying your types.

Comment: @kellys good call out. Its:

import { mapValues } from 'lodash'. I have "@types/lodash": "^4.14.180" as a dependency

Comment: It is indeed wrecking the type of `stateWrapper`: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbziAhmAaigNgVwKYDOcAvnAGZQQhwBEWEAJigQBY0DcAsAFA8DGEAHYF4IlDDwB1KGjB4ocALxwAFGIkAuAAwBKJQD5EPOHAHD4Adxlg5C5QmMnywQQwAKlMsCx4VSYAwkGohwAcEiUC4A5iR6SI5OTgD0SQB06QkkADSZzACegnzkeDB8LB4QXj5+oYHEwf4M4TCRgjHEcZmJKempmcQ53In5hcWl5Z7ehH4BAIJQMnn1IXMLKHnNrVEA2gC6sUZDiclpGUcmxI6XR1AlOFCCyGiYuNNWsvJZqmR6ioYqMDyckq5CUimUAHIyDhCjBgEIIXAAPzkVIAIxcDBU7xs8j0wR+Oh41x4gLkcAAqiwAPIsJRwABKdweABUgXgADxkvAg9RSay2fRcbgpJwAPSRQA)

Comment: You might want an alternative to `mapValues` that preserves the type of `stateWrapper`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The user @kellys provided a suggestion that led to the solution below:*

Replace lodash's `mapValues()` with

```
const mapValues = (obj, callback) => {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => [k, callback(v)]))
}
```

where your new mapValues() is defined in a Typescript file.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best answer but may be you can try adding this line above your function
//@ts-ignore

OR

try this

```
async fetchProfile({ id:any }: { id: string }) {
    ...
},
```

Comment: thanks for the tips. Writing //@ts-ignore above every function call is a bit cluttered for my liking (placing //ts-ignore only above the function declaration doesn't change anything). The code snippet proposal only renames the key from `id` to `any`.